# How to draw a node as an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, nodes

So far I have this code that generates 4 boxes side by side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{arw} = [retangle, minimum width=3cm,
                      minimum height=2cm,
                      text centered, 
                      fill=green!40]
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.2cm]
    \node (inicio)[arw] {inicio};
    \node (meio)[arw, right of=inicio] {meio};
    \node (outro meio)[arw, right of=meio] {outro meio};
    \node (fim) [arw, right of=outro meio] {fim};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I want something like this: (nodes are the arrows)

```
+--------+.  +---------+.  +---------+.  +---------+
|  text     >  >  here    >  >  and    >  >  here  |
+--------+´  +---------+´  +---------+´  +---------+
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Is there a way instead of using a rectangle, another command like "arrow" or something?

Comment: For in-text use of something similar, consider [`menukeys`](//ctan.org/pkg/menukeys): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVxuZ.png

Answer (score 7):

One easy option is to use a `smartdiagram`. The package documentation is [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/smartdiagram/smartdiagram.pdf) for more options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{inicio, meio, outro meio, fim}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there. Such arrows come with the `shapes.symbols` library. Please note that the syntax `right of` is deprecated (and not even part of the pgfmanual any more), please use the `positioning` library with its syntax `right=of`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{arw/.style={signal, minimum width=3cm,
                      minimum height=2cm,signal from=west,
                      text centered,fill=#1                 }}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt]
    \node [arw=blue] (inicio) {inicio};
    \node [arw=red,right=of inicio](meio) {meio};
    \node [arw=green, right=of meio] (outro meio){outro meio};
    \node [arw=orange, right=of outro meio] (fim){fim};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to add `signal from=east` to ìnicio` and `signal to=nowhere` to `fim` in order to get the proposed example.