# Tikz: draw arrow as node inside axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows, nodes, tikz-node

Yes I know there's a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461857/how-to-draw-a-node-as-an-arrow), but I'd need something simpliest.
I would like to reproduce this image, and my idea was to draw the two arrows (the ones corresponding to m=+1/2 and m=-1/2) as two nodes, and then report the words as nodes of nodes.
How can I draw two nodes as arrows?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth}
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
            grid=none,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
            ymin=0,ymax=100,
            xmin=0,xmax=100,
            ticks=none,
            axis lines = middle,
            %y axis line style = {stealth-},
            width=7cm,
            height=7cm,
            set layers,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            xlabel={$B_0$},ylabel={$E$},
            style={thick}
        ]
        \addplot [blue,dotted,very thick,domain=0:80] {+0.4*x + 50};
        \addplot [blue,dotted,very thick,domain=0:80] {-0.4*x + 50};
        \draw[<->] (65,76) -- (65,24) node [midway, left] {$\Delta E$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\draw[->] (85,85) -- (85,76) node[below] {$m$};`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, with really minimal MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Stealth,
lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=black, right}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    width=7cm,
    height=8cm,
    axis lines = left,
    xmin=0, xmax=120,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ticks=none,
    xlabel={$B_0$}, ylabel={$E$},
    no marks,
    samples=2,  domain=0:75,
every axis plot post/.append style={blue, very thick, densely dotted},
        ]
\addplot    {+0.4*x + 50} node[lbl]  {$\left\downarrow m = -\mfrac{1}{2}\right.$};
\addplot    {-0.4*x + 50} node[lbl]  {$\left\uparrow   m =  \mfrac{1}{2}\right.$};

\draw[<->] (65,76) --  node [lbl] {$\Delta E$} (65,24);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]